# FirstOrDefault throws NotSupportedException

Tags: realm

I've tried to use FirstOrDefault to return null if an object was not found in the database, as in:

```
var test = realmDb.All<UserContextReal>().FirstOrDefault();
```

however it throws a NotSupportedException...

is this expected? i usually use firstOrDefault to try to fetch an item and then react based on the returned value. currently i am working round this using Any() to check if an object is in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid `FirstOrDefault` is just not supported yet. You can see in [the source](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/master/Realm.Shared/linq/RealmResultsVisitor.cs#L119-L203) what LINQ methods are supported.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is

`var test = realmDb.All<UserContextReal>().First();`